# Why wildfly17 server show 403 where jboss 6.X work perfectly in my System?

Tags: java, http, server, jboss, wildfly

I use jboss 6.x to deploy war file (EMC.war) and jboss server work perfectly in eclipse with JRE1.8.0_241.

After changing server form jboss 6.X to wildfly 17, message always show 403 forbidden when using simple example.

I change wildfly version form 8 to 18, but http message still show 4.3 forbidden

There is my code.

[image]

My url is http://localhost:8080/EMC/

enviroment：
Eclipse
JRE 1.8.0_241
wildfly 17

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't post code as a picture.  Post the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that the code you're showing worked at all.

Your application should be in it's own class.  Something like:

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class BaseApplication extends Application {
    // intentionally empty
}
```

is sufficient.  Note that in this example I'm setting the base of the JAX-RS URL path.  Every URL will contain my web-app name and this path.  This path can be "/" if you'd like. Then, place your service code in it's own class like you have.  Do not extend `Application` for each service.

Answer (score 0):

I still get error 403.

Here is project structure.

In class RestEasyServices

```
package com.demo.tutorials;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class RestEasyServices extends Application {
}
```

In class EMCRESTService

```
package com.demo.tutorials;  

import java.io.BufferedReader;  
import java.io.InputStream;  
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;  
import javax.ws.rs.GET;  
import javax.ws.rs.POST;  
import javax.ws.rs.Path;  
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;  
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;  

@Path("/abc")
public class EMCRESTService extends Application{  

     @GET
     @Path("/simple")
     public String getHelloWorldJSON() {
            return "{\"result\":\"" + "\"}";
       } 

}
```

In web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>EMC</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

server.log show message doing http://localhost:8080/EMC/

```
2020-06-02 10:08:26,761 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (default task-1) PBOX00354: Setting security roles ThreadLocal: null
```

http://localhost:8080/EMC/ get 403

What should I do to solve the bug?

Thsanks!